# Make rounded cornered rectangle into speech bubble and position mage relative both in svg

Tags: javascript, extjs, svg

I am trying to make an SVG rectangle into a speech bubble, something like the following - http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/mek5Z/ but using SVG rather than CSS

The SVG HTML looks like this (I am actually using Extjs, and this is the HTML output of the SVG draw component);

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="300" height="45" id="ext-gen1408" style="width: 300px; height: 45px;">
    <defs></defs>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" stroke="none" opacity="0" id="ext-gen1409"></rect>
    <rect id="ext-sprite-1404" zIndex="0" width="100%" height="100%" stroke="#eb5439" fill="#fbcbc1" x="0" y="0" r="10" stroke-width="1" ry="10" rx="10" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></rect>
    <text id="ext-sprite-1405" zIndex="0" text="Sample text" fill="#ce2700" font="14px" x="10" y="15" text-anchor="start" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><tspan x="10" dy="3.625">Sample text</tspan></text>
    <image id="ext-sprite-1406" xlink:href="images/cross.png" zIndex="0" src="images/20110215-feat-html5.png" width="24" height="24" x="265" y="5" preserveAspectRatio="none" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></image>
 </svg>
```

How would I go about adding the arrow, either at the bottom or to the left e.t.c? Also, is there a way to make so that the image is placed relative to the top and right edges of the rectangle, so that when it is resized the image position remains at the same distance from the edges. or if relative positioning is not possible, how do I go about achieving the desired effect.

Comment: SVG can't do automatically expanding text boxes.  Are you ok with that?

Comment: Do you really have to implement it with SVG? In css3 you can create speech bubbles with css only. See http://www.css3shapes.com

Comment: Why are you using rect's - you should be using filled paths with a shadow filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
<svg width="100%" height="1000">
    <defs>
        <filter id="shadow">
           <feGaussianBlur in='SourceAlpha' stdDeviation='2.5' result='blur' />
            <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 .35 0" result="blur"/>
           <feMerge>
              <feMergeNode in='blur'/>
              <feMergeNode in='SourceGraphic'/>
           </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>

    <g transform="translate(30,5)">
        <g fill="#f2f2f2" filter="url(#shadow)">
            <rect width="107" height="40" rx="5" ry="5"/>
            <path d="M -20 20 l 21 -10 0 20 z"/>
        </g>
        <text x="53" y="25" text-anchor="middle">Hello there!</text>
    </g>

</svg>
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/x8S3M/1/)

Comment: Beautifully done BigBadaboom, many thanks! Is the second part of the question also possible? i.e. "is there a way to make so that the image is placed relative to the top and right edges of the rectangle..." e.t.c...

Thanks again...

Comment: There is no sort of automatic positioning in SVG like there is in HTML.  However I put a transform in the root group for each bubble in the demo.  You can modify those to position your bubbles.  For the code above, that is the `transform="translate(30,5)"`.